# How to apply string query filters in Odata

Tags: odata

My Odata collection returns a collection which includes the following field:

```
<d:ColorFlagInfo>Red,Blue</d:ColorFlagInfo>

<d:ColorFlagInfo>Red,Green</d:ColorFlagInfo>


<d:ColorFlagInfo>Black,Brown</d:ColorFlagInfo>
```

Can someone please help me with constructing an Odata query that filters by one or more particular color:

I’ve tried the following to get a particular color:

http://odata.test.com/cars?$filter=substringof(‘Black’, ColorFlagInfo)

http://odata.test.com/cars?$filter= ColorFlagInfo%20eq%20'Black'

How would I find all ColarFlagInfo containing the color green?

Comment: Could you share your edm model about the ColorFlagInfo property and the containing type? Doesn't $filter=substringof(‘Green’, ColorFlagInfo) work?

Answer (score 2):

In OData V3, we don't have Enum type. OData V4 does.

What is your service implemented with? WebAPI OData or WCF DS.

For WebAPI OData:

- In V3, the 'substringof' function cannot be applied to an enum type.
  You need to append all possible condition

  *$filter=ColorFlagInfo eq 'Green' or ColorFlagInfo eq 'Red,Green' or ....*
- In V4, you can use `has` operator on enum type.

  *$filter=ColorFlagInfo has Namespace.ColorFlagInfoTypeName'Green'*

Comment: How would one search by the int value of the enum now? I don't want to search by the namespace, I want to search by the value.

Comment: @JamesHancock, this can be done, see my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490430/odata-v4-webapi-filter-by-int-value-of-enum/34874182#34874182