# OData V4 + WebAPI Filter by Int Value of Enum?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

OData V4 has enum support but it appears you have to search by the namespace only. How does one now search by the value instead of the text representation?

In V3 of odata you could query for `$filter=Status eq 35`, where `35` is `Complete` in the enum. This method would work, even if that field was an enum field in the data model.

Now this method fails in V4, instead requiring the namespace with text representation of the enum.

I want to get the V3 support working again without having to lose the other features of odata V4. Searching by the int value for the enum item seems more reliable than searching for text. Older odata clients (such as kendo) don't support a by-text enum filtering method.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with V3, but as far as I know, I don't think $filter=Status eq 35 is supported if Status is a enum. If I'm wrong, would you kindly provide the link to the specification or examples?

Comment: OData V3 didn't know anything about enums so it worked as you would expect and you could just pass the integer value behind the enum value and you got your filter.
The issue with the new implementation is that combo boxes that are bound to an enum, or database value that is stored as an int, cannot filter because they can't possibly know the namespace and value, they only know the int. Hence I'm trying to find a way to $filter by the int instead of the namespace enum value since this is a very common scenario that needs to be supported. If V4 doesn't support it, then I'd consider it a bug.

Comment: An additional problem in requiring the namespace prefix is that the API breaks when the enum is moved to another namespace (for example as part of a refactoring). The only workaround I can think of is to model the enum property as an `int` in your EDM model if you can.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

to do that in OData v4, we can enable the EnumPrefixFree in the initial webapi configuration, so we dont have to write the full enum namespace as prefix :

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // ...
    config.EnableEnumPrefixFree(enumPrefixFree: true);
    config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", YourEdmModem);
    // ...
}
```

then, we can filter any enum by String or Int value :

```
$filter=Status eq 'single'
```

or

```
$filter=Status eq 1
```

hope this helps.

Comment: If I wanted to get this to work with my already existing routes how would I map the odata service route? Also what is "YourEdmModem"? I'm using DTOs that are returned via Linq To Entities with Select

Comment: As this is the marked answer: They removed this extension method in a recent release: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/904 Could you please update the answer?

Comment: EnableEnumPrefix was removed

Answer (score 9):

With v4, you have to add the namespace as the prefix and surround the value with the single quote such as http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(m1bhpaebr1yvzx5vtz5v4ur1))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$filter=Gender%20eq%20Microsoft.OData.SampleService.Models.TripPin.PersonGender'1' , where 1 represents Female.

Here is a quotation from the ABNF of the protocol http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/abnf/odata-abnf-construction-rules.txt:

```
enum            = qualifiedEnumTypeName SQUOTE enumValue SQUOTE
enumValue       = singleEnumValue *( COMMA singleEnumValue )
singleEnumValue = enumerationMember / enumMemberValue
enumMemberValue = int64Value
```

Comment: Right, that's the problem. They've completely forgot the use case of combo controls hooked to enum fields. The combo will ALWAYS have the int value behind the enum, not the namespace mess.

I'm hoping that someone who designed the standard wasn't so ridiculously short sighted that they didn't ignore the most likely use case.